# How to make IntelliJ IDEA leave some of my new lines alone?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, coding-style, code-formatting

I have the following code:

```
return new StringBuilder()
    .append("raw/")
    .append(dt.format(prefixFormatter))
    .append("/")
    .append(guid)
    .append("/")
    .append(filename)
    .toString();
```

IDEA is hell bent on formatting it like this:

```
return new StringBuilder().append("raw/").append(dt.format(prefixFormatter)).append("/")
        .append(guid).append("/").append(filename).toString();
```

How can I take back control of this formatting rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Preferences**, **Editor**, **Code Style**, **Java**, **Wrapping and Spaces**. Under the subtitle **Keep when reformatting**, check **line breaks**.

[image]

On my Mac, the **Preferences** menu is found under the **IntelliJ** menu. The keyboard shortcut is  <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The correct option is `Chained function calls`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38596350/599743