# Wrapping chained method calls on a separate line in Intellij for Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, word-wrap

[Copied from]: [Wrapping chained method calls on a separate line in eclipse for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275785/wrapping-chained-method-calls-on-a-separate-line-in-eclipse-for-java)

For example, I have this:

`someObject.A().B().C();`

But I really want this:

```
someObject.A()
          .B()
          .C();
```

I wanted to ask how to achieve that formatting in intellij. I was unable to achieve it. I want to use the same formatting given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275785/wrapping-chained-method-calls-on-a-separate-line-in-eclipse-for-java/10446098#10446098).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Small disclaimer:** this is IJ 14.4, it's possible that in later versions it may have been changed/renamed/etc, but it should be there somewhere nonetheless

---

Go to `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code style` -> `Java` and select the `Wrapping and Braces` tab, then scroll to `Chained method calls`. Check the little combo on the right of the item, default `Do not wrap`, and change it to `Wrap always`.

[image: Chained method wrapping]

Depending on your prefference, you may want to also consider the next `Align when multiline` checkbox

[image: Align when multiline]

Comment: If you want builder pattern recognition, please see this feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122600

Comment: Still valid in 2019.2. It's well worth to take some time and review all options. Auto align makes comparing code in a three-way diff a breeze.