# AppCode chained call indents?

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode

Is there any way to get AppCode to indent chained calls? For example it currently formats this;

```
Test.writeString("test", value: "Test")
.then {
    print("1")
}
.always {
    print("1")
}
```

I'd like it to format to;

```
Test.writeString("test", value: "Test")
    .then {
        print("1")
    }
    .always {
        print("1")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a mac to install Appcode and validate this and the [docs don't provide much info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/2016.1/configuring-code-style.html?search=wrapping), but I would expect it to have something similar to Idea in the `Editor` -> `Code style` section under `Wrapping and braces`. Take a look at [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595138/wrapping-chained-method-calls-on-a-separate-line-in-intellij-for-java/38596350#38596350) for a similar java related question and let us know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

[This feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-12654) is not yet implemented in the current release. We plan to add it into [AppCode 2016.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2016/08/appcode-2016-3-roadmap/) which is planned for the end of the year.